# Simple ArrayList question

Tags: java, list, arrays

I have this class:

```
public class User {


    public User(String nickname, String ipAddress) {

        nickname = nickname.toLowerCase();
        System.out.println(nickname + " " + ipAddress);
    }
}
```

And another class that creates an array containing User objects.

```
class UserMananger {

    static User user;
    static User user2;
    static User user3;

    static ArrayList allTheUsers;

       public void UserManager() {

           allTheUsers = new ArrayList();

           user = new User("Slavisha", "123.34.34.34");
           user2 = new User("Zare", "123.34.34.34");
           user3 = new User("Smor", "123.34.34.34");

           allTheUsers.add(user);
           allTheUsers.add(user2);
           allTheUsers.add(user3);


       }
}
```

What I want to do is to call a main method that will give me all elements from the list that are type User in format: "nickname ipAddress"

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println(allTheUsers.get(0));
    }
```

For example, this main method should give me something like:
Slavisha 123.34.34.34
but it doesn't. What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First problem: you haven't overridden `toString()` in `User`. For example:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return nickname + " " + ipAddress;
}
```

Second problem: each time an instance of `UserManager` is created, you're changing the values of your static variables... but you're not doing anything *unless* an instance of `UserManager` is created. One option is to change the constructor of UserManager into a static initializer:

```
static {
    // Initialize the static variables here
}
```

Third problem: you haven't shown us where your `main` method is, so we don't know whether it has access to `allTheUsers`.

Fourth problem: "it doesn't" isn't a good description of your problem. Always say what appears to be happening: are you getting an exception? Is it just printing the wrong thing?

Comment: I did that also but when I compile class User Manager there is an exception:
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at UserMananger.main(UserManager.java:29)
Java Result: 1
"

Comment: Right - that would be because you're not calling a constructor, so the initialization code is never getting run.